# What should I do if I come by a seemingly inappropriate profile picture?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to bring a seemingly in[appropriate profile picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153132/221866) to the moderators notice?

What should I do if I come by such a profile picture?

Comment: Answer is the same as in the linked dupe: flag one of the posts, or email the team. You can also bring this up in chat, usually there will be a moderator around to handle it instantly.