# Do we have any guidelines or regulations that deals with using profile image

Tags: support, profile-picture, abuse

As user can add any image for his profile which can be offensive or disgusting by accepted standards of morality and decency like obscene, vulgar, immoral, dirty etc.

So Stack Exchange have any guidelines or regulations that deals with using profile image? Or user is free to use any kind of image for profile.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153132/appropriate-profile-picture

Comment: Even though the duplicate doesn't look like duplicate at first glance, it contains official answer from SE employee which perfectly answer this question, explaining what is allowed as profile picture.